# SQL syntax to get all possible combinations when joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables T1, T2, T3 with values

```
 CREATE TABLE #T1
 (
      [user1] char(20)
 )

 INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D')

 CREATE TABLE #T2
 (
     [user2] char(20)
 )

 INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES ('D'), ('E'), ('F'), ('G')

 CREATE TABLE #T3
 (
     [user3] char(20)
 )

 INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES ('D'), ('E'), ('C'), ('H')
```

I want the result to by display like

```
user1   user2   user3
-------------------------
A       NULL    NULL
B       NULL    NULL
C       NULL    C
D       D       D
NULL    E       E
NULL    F       NULL
NULL    NULL    H
```

I tried this:

```
select 
    user1, 
    user2, 
    user3 
from 
    #T1 
full join 
    #T2 on #T1.user1 = #T2.user2 
full join 
    #T3 on #T2.user2 = #T3.user3
```

But obviously I missing something. Thanks for the help

Comment: You never insert data into `#T3`, it all goes into `#T1` and `#T2`.

Comment: No G row wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to add an extra predicate to the join on #T3. So this:

```
full outer join #T3 on #T2.user2 = #T3.user3
```

becomes this:

```
full outer join #T3 on #T2.user2 = #T3.user3 OR #t3.user3 = #T1.user1
```

I am assuming your sample data had a typo since you meant to insert into #t3 in the last section. And you posted desired output is also missing NULL, G, NULL

Here's the full corrected code:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    user1 char(20)
)

insert into #T1 VALUES ('A')
insert into #T1 VALUES ('B')
insert into #T1 VALUES ('C')
insert into #T1 VALUES ('D')

CREATE TABLE #T2
(
    user2 char(20)
)

insert into #T2 VALUES ('D')
insert into #T2 VALUES ('E')
insert into #T2 VALUES ('F')
insert into #T2 VALUES ('G')

 CREATE TABLE #T3
 (
    user3 char(20)
 )

 insert into #T3 VALUES ('D')
 insert into #T3 VALUES ('E')
 insert into #T3 VALUES ('C')
 insert into #T3 VALUES ('H')

select 
    user1, 
    user2, 
    user3 
from #T1 
full outer join #T2 on #T1.user1 = #T2.user2 
full outer join #T3 on #T2.user2 = #T3.user3 OR #t3.user3 = #T1.user1

drop table #T1
drop table #T2
drop table #T3
```

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this to put the important part at the top.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn the join predicates? Feel free to edit this if it makes it more clear or better. I reposted all the sample data so it was inserting into the correct tables.

Comment: Thanks to both, you are the best.